# Motherboard recognizes platter drive; consistently fails with SSD (SMART HDD/SSD failure)

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

#### System

- Motherboard: [Asus Maximus VIII Hero](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/) (Bios 1701: latest bios)
- SSD: [Corsair Neutron XT SSD](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/ssd/neutron-series-xt)
- Windows 7 x64 / Windows 10 x64

#### Issue

After months of running without issue (Win 7 x64), my Corsair Neutron XT SSD stopped being recognized by my Asus Maximus VIII Hero motherboard. The specific error I receive during boot up is:

> SMART detected HDD/SSD failure 1 : Corsair Neutron XT SSD

I RMA'd the SSD with Corsair and upon receiving the new SSD, I was able to successfully install Windows 10 x64. Immediately after the first reboot, I received the same error (see above).

*FWIW: I reset my BIOS and then did a CMOS reset before installing the OS. on the new SSD.*

Initially, I thought the error was due to the SSD failing. Now I'm not convinced. If I go into the BIOS and override the boot drive, I can successfully boot into the OS. By override, I am seeing 3 boot options:

1. Boot Option #1: UEFI: HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH14NS40 (3894MB)
2. Boot Option #2: P1: Corsair Neutron XT SSD (228936MB)
3. Boot Option #3: P6: HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH14NS40 (3894MB)

For reference:

- Boot Option #1 was not present prior to installing the new O.S.
- P1 is the SSD drive
- P6 is the BluRay drive

If I use Boot Option #2, I can successfully boot into my O.S. I've been unable to disable Boot Option #1 which always gives the error above.

#### Question

- Are there BIOS setting I need to configure for UEFI enabled BIOS and SSDs to successfully boot?

Here are a series of images showing the original error and the BIOS Boot options:

Boot error:

[image: Boot Error 1]

Boot options:

[image: Boot Error 2]

Boot options close-up:

[image: Boot Options]

Boot Compatibility Support:

[image: Compatibility Support]

Boot/Secure Boot options:

[image]

Comment: The boot option you point out, is perfectly normally, its allowing you to boot a optical disk in UEFI mode.  You have secure boot enabled, which means, you can only boot to UEFI enabled devices.  Which means settings things to legacy, is conflicting, with stuff.

Comment: **I've been unable to disable Boot Option #1 which always gives the error above.** - Because I presume you don't have a bootable disk in your optical disk drive 100% of the time.  *Launch CSM** -> Enable that is your problem.  **Is there some Bios setting I need to configure for UEFI enabled Bios and SSD's to successfully boot?** - Yeah don't enable legacy mode.  Everyone has this strange desire to enable legacy mdoe but attempt to use secure boot and GPT partitions.

Comment: I should have clarified that whether the legacy support is enabled or disabled, the same issue occurs with the SSD not being recognized. I will double check when I get home, but I did not recall having the optical disk in my drive when I took these picture. I'll post an update in a couple of hours.

Comment: Your drive is going to be offered even if you don't have a disk, so the third option is "legacy" option for an optical disk, while the 1st option is the UEFI (optical) option.

Comment: I reset the bios. Boot option #1 is gone. And replaced with #2 which was replaced by #3. The same error occurs. The only way to bypass the error is to enter the bios and manually select the ssd to boot from; the ssd is already set as priority #1, though.

Comment: I chatted with Asus support and they insisted the SSD was defective (both SSD's). After further chatting, they suggested I disable SMART check in the BIOS... after disabling SMART check, no issues with starting/rebooting. I'll try another new SSD later, but for now, this does seem to solve the issue.